# How to insert a non-inline picture into a word document using VB6?

Tags: ms-word, vb6

I am trying to insert an image into a word document using the Microsoft word 15.0 objects library included with VB^ and the only way I've seen to insert a graphics file is through this:

```
oDoc.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.jpg")
```

But, I want a picture that can be positioned over the text and where I want it in the document... Is there any way to do this using VB6 Code?

Comment: Record a macro to do what you want first. Then use that as a start to figuring out your automation code. Come back with your code and results and what's not working for you

Comment: @dbmitch In this case, if graphics are inserting as InlineShapes by default, it's difficult to record a macro since *all* graphics are going to insert like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word has two different ways to manage images and other embedded objects: as `InlineShapes` and as `Shapes`. The first are treated the same as characters in the text flow; the latter have text wrap foramtting and "live" in a different layer from the text.

To insert a graphics file as a `Shape`:

```
Dim shp as Word.Shape
Set shp = oDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName, LinkToFile, _
          SaveWithDocument, Left, Top, Width, Height, Anchor)
```

The `AddPicture` method returns a `Shape` object. Often, this is useful when additional properties need to be set after the object has been inserted. For example in order to specify the text wrap formatting. If no `Shape` object is required a `Shape` can be inserted without assigning to an object. In this case, leave out the parentheses:

```
oDoc.Shapes.AddPicture FileName, LinkToFile, _
          SaveWithDocument, Left, Top, Width, Height, Anchor
```

While only the `FileName` argument is required, the last argument - `Anchor` - is very important if you want to control *where* the image is positioned when it's inserted.

It's also possible to insert as an `InlineShape` then use `ConvertToShape` in order to have a `Shape` object to which text wrap formatting can be applied.

Every `Shape` *must* be associated with a Range in the document. Unless otherwise specified, this will be the first character of the paragraph wherein the current selection is. I strongly recommend passing a `Range` to the `Shapes.AddPicture` method in the `Anchor` argument for this reason.

Note that once a `Shape` has been inserted there's no direct way to change the `anchor` position. It can be done using cut & paste. Another possibility is to use the `ConvertToInlineShape` method so that you can work with the `Range` to move the graphic, then `ConvertToShape` to turn it back into a `Shape`, but in this case a number of positioning and wrap properties may need to be reset. Here an example of using the "convert" methods:

```
Sub MoveShapeToOtherRange()
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
    Dim rngEnd As Word.Range, rngStart As Word.Range

    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set rngStart = oDoc.content
    rngStart.Collapse wdCollapseStart 'start of document
    Set rngEnd = Selection.Range

    Set shp = oDoc.shapes.AddPicture(fileName:="C:\Test\icons\Addin_Icon16x16.png", _
              Top:=0, Left:=10, anchor:=rngStart)

    Set ils = shp.ConvertToInlineShape
    Set rngStart = ils.Range
    rngEnd.FormattedText = rngStart.FormattedText
    rngStart.Delete
    Set ils = oDoc.InlineShapes(1)
    Set shp = ils.ConvertToShape
End Sub
```

By default, a `Shape` will insert with `MoveWithText` activated. That means the position on the page is not set, editing will affect the vertical position. If you want the `Shape` to always be centered on the page, for example, set this to false. Note, however, that if the anchor point moves to a different page, the `Shape` will also move to that page.

On occasion, the `Left` and `Top` arguments don't "take" when adding a `Shape` - you may need to set these again as properties after adding it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, when I try to use the code with <oDoc.Shapes.AddPicture...> it comes up with the error, "Expected: =". Do you think you can provide a code example of what you mean by converting it to inline shape and then back. I get the idea of what you are saying, but how I implement it all is a bit confusing, especially the range and the anchor part. I appreciate your response

Comment: I've addressed your problem using edits in the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, What I ended up doing that worked was this:

```
Dim a As Object
On Error Resume Next
a = oDoc.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.jpg", , , 25, 25, 25, 25)
```

For some reason, This places the image at the position and size. When I looked at the docs for ".AddPicture" I realized it returns a Shapes object. So I just had it store it in a throw-away object. For some reason it then would respond with an error, but would end up placing on the doc anyways. So I used:

`On Error Resume Next`

This skips the error. After that, the picture places as expected and the rest of the doc is made as expected

Thank you for your answers